# Why mail sent ends up in Junkbox when we use variable value?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi Please let me know what is wrong in my code

Mail Always send in JunkBox when condition in if not else

```
$comObj = new companies();
$companyData = $comObj->getCompanyDataPDF ( $params );

$companyData[0]['term_condition'] = nl2br($companyData[0]['term_condition']);
$proposalData = $objProposal->getSavedData ( $id );

$mergeData = array_merge ( array ('companyData' => $companyData ), array ('proposalData' => $proposalData ) );

$htmlcontent = $this->view->partial("companyapi/pdf.phtml", $mergeData);

require_once('html2fpdf/html2pdf.class.php');

$name_of_pdf = trim($proposalData[0]['proposal_name']).'pdf_'.time().'.pdf';

$pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');


$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlcontent);

$new_pdf= $pdf->Output('', 'S');


$filepath= PUBLIC_PATH.'tempPdf/'.$name_of_pdf;
$rootpathforcheckfile = IMG_HARD_DRIVE_PATH.'tempPdf/'.$name_of_pdf;
$temp_array = array();

$temp_array["pdf"] = $new_pdf;
$temp_array["pdf_name"] = $name_of_pdf;

$customername="Customer";
$companyname="";
if($params ['customerName']){
$customername=$params ['customerName'];
}
if($companyData[0]['name']){
$companyname=$companyData[0]['name'];
}

if(isset($proposalData[0]['proposal_name']) && $proposalData[0]['proposal_name'] != ''){
$subject = (string)strtoupper($proposalData[0]['proposal_name']);

}else {
$subject = "Proposal Mail";
}
$sndemail =Email_Mailer::sendMail($subject,'Please find attached proposal',$customername,$params ['custEmail'],$temp_array,$companyname,$companyData[0]['email']);
```

My mail function :::

```
public static function sendMail($subject,$message,$recipentname='',$recipentemail,$filesPathArray,$sendername='',$senderemail)
    {  
        try 
         {
             $mail = new Zend_Mail();
             $mail->setBodyHtml($formated_msg);
             $mail->setFrom($senderemail);
             $mail->addTo($recipentemail,$recipentname);
             $mail->addCc($senderemail,$sendername);
             $mail->setSubject($subject);
             //attachments code
             if( !empty($filesPathArray) )
             { 

                      $at = new Zend_Mime_Part($filesPathArray["pdf"]);
                      $at->type = 'pdf';
                      $at->filename = $filesPathArray["pdf_name"];
                      $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
                      $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
                     $mail->addAttachment($at);

             } else {

             }

              $mail->send();  
             return true;
         }
         catch (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $e) 
         {
             //throw $e;
             return false;
         }
         catch (Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception $e)
         {
             //throw $e;
             return false;
         }
         catch (Zend_Exception $e)
         {
             //throw $e;
             return false;
         }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post the mail's sourcecode here. Mailspam detection is more complicated than simple word filtering and therefore can have many (individual) reasons.

Comment: @DanFromGermany if I change subject veriable value strtouppar($proposalData[0]['proposal_name']); then its working fine but if lower letter then its send mail in junck box

Comment: There is a bracket missing `Data[0]'proposal` before the `'` and `strtouppar` should be written `strtoupper`. Maybe you have SYNTAX ERROR bla in your mail. Post the sourecode of the mail...

Comment: @DanFromGermany code posted

Comment: this is not the email sourcecode... it looks like this: http://help.runbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Mail_5.png

Comment: @DanFromGermany please check http://jsfiddle.net/kuldeepraj48/ztt3r/ is my zend mail object with source code

Comment: You have to go into your mail client, and on the email in the junk folder hit "Show sourcecode of the mail" or something like that. Not PHP sourcecode. Also sometimes in the mail headers, the spamfilter leaves a comment WHY it has put it into junkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the mail system you are sending to is flagging the mail as spam. You should investigate this  there, and possibly re-ask this question on serverfault.

Given the general generic-ness of the message, I'm not altogether suprised. Either work on making the mail details clearer on what it contains (so it doesn't trigger the filters) or look at something like dkim to prove who you are so it is no longer flagged.